# drupal 7 : create xls file with views bulk operation

Tags: php, drupal-7, phpexcel, xls, vbo

I'm trying to generate an excel file using PHPExcel Module in the `action_info` function with the following code :

```
function mymodule_export_data_action(&$object, $context = array()) {
if (isset($object->uid)) {
    $uid = $object->uid;
}
elseif (isset($context['uid'])) {
    $uid = $context['uid'];
}
if ($uid) {
    module_load_include('inc', 'phpexcel');
    $filename = 'mymodule--download-' . uniqid() . '.xls';
    $filepath = variable_get('file_public_path', conf_path() . '/files') . '/' . $filename;
    $result = phpexcel_export(
            array('Nom', 'Prenom', 'Date de naissance', 'Adresse email'), 
                    array(
                    array('A1', 'B1'),
                    array('A2', 'B2'),
                  ), $filepath);
    if ($result === PHPEXCEL_SUCCESS) {
        drupal_set_message(l('Click to download', $filepath));
    }
    else {

    }
}
```

}

This is working pretty fine when having just one node, but when there's more than one it generates a new file for each one, which also good but my purpose is to have one file for all nodes. It has been days and I really hope for someone to put me in the right direction.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You need to filter out specific nodes and exports filtered node, right?

Comment: Exactly, and i can't use Views Data Export becouse the user have to choose (via checkbox) which of the filtred nodes he wants to export

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution by using [views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module, [views_data_export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module, 2 lines of PHP code and some lines of jQuery.

Just follow these steps:

**1st** Install `views` and `views_data_export` modules

**2nd (a)** Create views page and data export, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssOF3nPgcfc)
  will help you to export the data according to the
    filter(s)

**2nd (b)** Don't forget to add **nid field** in the `views page` that will use to get NIDs

**2nd (c)** Now, create *one more views data export* (that again [starts here](https://youtu.be/ssOF3nPgcfc?t=207), if you need) and create exporting PATH different than the first data export (**created** on step 2nd (a)) **but** keep remember you don't have to update `Attach to` option under the [DATA EXPORT SETTINGS](https://snag.gy/VhrbFo.jpg) section, it should looks like this `Attach to: none`.

**2nd (d)** Now, add **nid** as *contextual filter* in the views and choose **Provide default value** = **Content ID from URL** [like this](https://snag.gy/idZNkL.jpg) and check the checkbox `Allow multiple values` [like this](https://snag.gy/xCIyvE.jpg)

**3rd** Add two lines of PHP code somewhere in the `template.php` **OR** top of the tpl of **views page** if you have already created (by the way I did it with the tpl named as `views-view--export-multiple-rows--page.tpl.php`).

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {                 
    drupal_goto("export_selected/".implode(',', $_POST['export']));
}
```

**4th** Add below jQuery code in the JS file that will be render on this page like `custom.js` and **change classes **

```
jQuery(function($){
    jQuery('.feed-icon a:first-child').text('Export All');

    jQuery('td.views-field-nid').each(function() { //class of NID added in step 2nd (b)
        var t = jQuery(this);
        var id = jQuery.trim(t.text());
        t.html('<input type="checkbox" name="export[]" value="" />');
        t.find('input').val(id);
    });
    //Below .view-export-multiple-rows class is of views class (main views page)
    $('.view-export-multiple-rows').wrap('<form method="POST" class="export-form"></form>');
    $('.export-form .view-content').append('<input type="submit" value="Export Selected" name="submit" />');
});
```

If you follow all these steps properly, I believe you have done with:

- To export all rows
- To export filtered rows
- To export specific rows

I hope this will help you or at least give you an idea.

Thanks